# Geoserver: Images coming thourgh as White Transparent Tiles

Tags: gis, geoserver

I downloaded certain areas of maos from Earthexplorer.  We used NAIP Aerial imagery.  We are having this occurrence at regular view the images look ok, but as the image gets zooned in more it has white layers on it.  When i view the tile in an image viewer as i zoom in further the white layer appears and zoom all the way out it reappears.

Here are 2 images of an area that was served to my application. They show the anomaly.

[image: IMAGE TILES OVERLAPPED]

[image: IMAGE TILES OVERLAPPED2]

And a single image showing a single tile at max zoom out where the anomaly is not there.

The other three images are a single tile at Zoom 0 - Zoom 10 and Zoom 11.

[image: ZOOM LEVEL 01]

[image: ZOOM LEVEL 10]

[image: ZOOM LEVEL 11]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated on how to remove those layers from displaying.

I have attempted re-downloading the images from EARTHEXPLORER to no avail.  There are older images in the Geoserver but they aren't very good, and would like to use the newer images with better resolution.  There are 120 Layers built in the geoserver from 400 meg to 2 gig.  Only the new latest images I downloaded from NAIP do this white tile transparent occurrence.

Comment: I think those white lines are roads - how did you add the imagery to GeoServer? what does the log file say is happening? which software are you using to display the image? is it using WMS or WMTS?

Comment: If you notice the images i provided, the last three show a single tile downloaded from the NAIP Aerial Imagery distribution.  Zoom level 0 is very clear, zoom level 10 is very clear, but at zoom level 11 ( the third picture) there is a white overlay to the image.  I am wanting the clarity from zoom 0 and zoom 10 to be same in all subsequent  zoom levels.

Comment: that is a colour balance issue. probably caused by the averaging that goes into the lower zoom levels.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Will this also effect the tiles as in image one?  Where all the tiles side side create the same effect?

Comment: How did you create the tile stack? How did you add them to GeoServer? what client are you using to display the map?